# ReasctJS, Firebase Messaging Token - get from Promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, firebase-cloud-messaging

New to development. Trying to use Firebase Messaging with a ReactJS app. I want to add the token to my headers so I can send to the backend:

```
instance.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
        const token = TokenService.getLocalAccessToken();
        const firebaseToken = getNewToken();
        if (token) {
            // config.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + token;  // for Spring Boot back-end
            config.headers["x-access-token"] = token; // for Node.js Express back-end
            config.headers["firebase-token"] = firebaseToken;
        }
        return config;
    },
    (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

..getToken points to the below:

```
export const getNewToken = async () => {
    let currentToken = '';
    try {
        currentToken = await getToken(messaging, {vapidKey: "MY_VAPID_KEY"});
        if (currentToken) {
            console.log(currentToken);
            //setTokenFound(true);
        } else {
            //setTokenFound(false);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token.', error);
    }
    return currentToken;
};
```

...And this shows the token in the console log correctly, but it is returned to headers as [object Promise] and I'm not sure what to do about it. I know this has something to do with the asynchronous nature of Promises and I have experimented with doing this using async/await functions - but the result is always the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Use await in getNewToken and you are good to go

Comment: Thanks - this was close to the right answer. See update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use `await` and that's it.

While calling an async function, you must `await` it to get the returned value.

```
const firebaseToken = await getNewToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to update my axios instance interceptor as such, adding async/await:

```
instance.interceptors.request.use(
    async config => {
        const token = TokenService.getLocalAccessToken();
        const firebaseToken = await getNewToken();
        if (token) {
            // config.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + token;  // for Spring Boot back-end
            config.headers["x-access-token"] = token; // for Node.js Express back-end
            config.headers["firebase-token"] = firebaseToken;
        }
        return config;
    },
    (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```